# How do I type a logical 'OR' i.e. (∨) in notepad?

Tags: windows, keyboard

I just wanted to know regarding typing a logical 'OR' i.e. `∨` (\u2228)

When I try to type  ALT+8744 (8744 being 2288(hex) in decimal), it works/ the `∨` appears ok in ms word or wordpad, but in notepad I get an apostrophe, even with a font that supports it such as arial unicode ms.

Comment: @barlop: I know that, but I want to know how to type it…

Comment: I just moved my comment into an answer and added how to type it. And if you knew that you were talking about logical OR and what font it was and what its utf-16 code was and saw it in charmap, then you should have written your question much better.

Comment: I've made some much needed improvements to your question(with my edit), but also, a minor point, your question would've been a bit clearer if you'd asked about logical AND since logical AND looks nothing like a V,  and if you can find the answer for how to do the AND then it'd apply to the OR too, but anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

Note, below shows how you can type it in word or wordpad, but it turned out the questioner wanted it in notepad and was getting an apostrophe.  Nevertheless, here's how to get it in word or notepad..

good question.. you're talking about logical OR  http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2228/index.htm  you can see logical OR and logical AND in charmap if you choose the font that has them , so arial ms unicode.  [image]

You can copy/paste it into ms word.. you can put your cursor after it and do alt-x and see its code. e.g. 2227. That's hex though. You can convert that into decimal with calc.

It shows the code is 8743 you can type that with alt, that's AND.

Logical AND. (looks like a pointy n) ∧  is 8743

Logical OR, The ∨ (which is technically not a V or v, it's a ∨), is 8744.

[image]

Comment: Alt+8743 types a '

Comment: @wb9688 it works for me.

Comment: @wb9688 ah it's working in ms word, but in notepad it seems to type a `'`

Comment: In every application it types a ', but Word has custom keyboard shortcuts…

Comment: @wb9688  I wouldn't call it a custom keyboard shortcut.  I notice  it works in wordpad too.